# Can we produce true 3D holograms yet?

Tags: video, animation, 3d

Do we currently have true 3d animated holograms yet? Images that we can walk around and see as 3d? I'm pretty sure we have this for still objects but I've seen plenty of videos of animated concert holograms and they are only looking face on at the stage.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you regard as "true 3d" but there is a technique called "Light Field Display" which has been in development for some time now. Its essentially still a 2D screen but you can walk around and look at it from different angle as if it were an actual 3d object.
http://gl.ict.usc.edu/Research/3DDisplay/

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the rotating mirror based systems.  It does technically produce a 3d image but uses a conventional projector and a rotating mirror.

Comment: that does look interesting and is the only "walkabout" example I've seen. There is also a in-process technology that claims it will bring holograms to consumers by late 2015 for $800. They dont really have any demo but have a project on indie gogo. https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/bleen-3d-without-glasses#home

Comment: Sounds like a scam tbh, they dont show a single real picture or video. Everything is rendered or stockfootage mixed with renderings.

Answer (score 1):

Not at a usable frame rate.  The fastest I'm aware of is one that updates every 2 seconds.  They are also not free floating in air, but rather projected within a block of material.  There is a nice article on discovery.com about the most advanced one I know of [here](http://news.discovery.com/tech/holographic-3d-tv.htm).

There are also vapor displays that can display a video floating in space, but those aren't actually 3d, just a 2d projection.

Comment: thanks. that article was from about 1.5 years ago and Blanche thought they would have results in a few months but when I checked his site I found his videos were blocked here by Youtube. Know any videos that show a person walking around a hologram?